# How do you rename machines in your domain remotely using powershell?

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell

How does one rename machines in an AD domain using Powershell?

Comment: And the down vote was for?

Comment: Can't speak to the other dv, but mine was due to the fact that you didn't show any evidence whatsoever that you tried to research this on your own before coming here. The command needed to do this was the first result for a search on "powershell rename computer".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Rename-Computer -NewName 'NewComputer' -ComputerName 'OldComputer' -Restart`

For further reading, `Get-Help Rename-Computer -Full`

(You might need to specify the `-DomainCredential` explicitly, just test it and use the Get-Help if you get stuck.)